# Importing MoonMap.js into my VueJS 2 project

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, ecmascript-5

I started a VueJS 2 project and I try to import a js I found which I need and is called [Moon Map](https://github.com/mitch-seymour/moonmap) but since it seems that VueJS is using ES6 javascript and I try to import an ES5 javascript file it won't compile and I receive errors.

Can anyone here tell me or show me an example of importing an ES5 script inside my VueJS project?

Thanks.

**EDIT - Still Relevant**

I try to implement in socialCircle.

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box header"><div v-html="logo" class="logo"></div></div>
      <div class="box content">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="socialCircle" v-for="social in socials">{{social.name}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'home',
    data () {
      return {
        logo: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="29.094 45.2 229.507 71.651"><defs><style>.a{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><g transform="translate(29.094 45.2)"><g transform="translate(0)"><path class="a" d="M40.978,28.779V53.461a75.52,75.52,0,0,1-12.461,1.2c-9.585,0-16.775-2.157-21.328-6.47C2.4,43.876,0,37.406,0,28.3,0,19.433,2.4,12.723,7.189,8.41S18.931,1.7,28.037,1.7a44.489,44.489,0,0,1,11.5,1.438v7.668a41.366,41.366,0,0,0-10.784-1.2,25.908,25.908,0,0,0-10.544,1.917,13.688,13.688,0,0,0-6.231,5.991c-1.438,2.636-2.157,6.47-2.157,10.784,0,6.47,1.438,11.023,4.313,14.139q4.313,4.313,13.659,4.313a26.045,26.045,0,0,0,4.313-.24V28.779Z" transform="translate(0 2.374)"/><path class="a" d="M21.838,9.287A4.877,4.877,0,0,1,20.4,5.693,4.521,4.521,0,0,1,21.838,2.1C22.8,1.14,24.234.9,26.151.9a7.115,7.115,0,0,1,4.313,1.2A4.877,4.877,0,0,1,31.9,5.693a4.113,4.113,0,0,1-1.438,3.595c-.959.959-2.4,1.2-4.313,1.2A7.115,7.115,0,0,1,21.838,9.287Zm-.24,45.77v-38.1H30.7v38.1Z" transform="translate(28.486 1.257)"/><path class="a" d="M28.5,56.314V0h9.106V56.314Z" transform="translate(39.796)"/><path class="a" d="M59.5,8.838a10.314,10.314,0,0,1,5.272,4.793c1.2,2.157,1.677,5.272,1.677,9.106V46.221H58.784l-.719-3.834h-.479a11.712,11.712,0,0,1-4.313,3.355,16.686,16.686,0,0,1-5.991,1.2,14.268,14.268,0,0,1-6.47-1.438,9.052,9.052,0,0,1-4.074-3.834A11.385,11.385,0,0,1,35.3,35.917c0-3.595,1.2-6.231,3.595-8.148s6.231-3.115,11.5-3.595l7.189-.719V22.018a8.568,8.568,0,0,0-.959-4.553,5.6,5.6,0,0,0-2.876-2.4,15.488,15.488,0,0,0-5.272-.719,35.751,35.751,0,0,0-5.032.479,34.006,34.006,0,0,0-5.272,1.2V9.077a34.578,34.578,0,0,1,5.751-1.2A54.772,54.772,0,0,1,49.918,7.4,26.926,26.926,0,0,1,59.5,8.838ZM54.231,39.511a10.8,10.8,0,0,0,3.355-2.4V28.967l-6.231.479c-2.4.24-4.074.719-5.272,1.677a4.469,4.469,0,0,0-1.677,3.834,5.059,5.059,0,0,0,1.438,3.834,5.858,5.858,0,0,0,4.313,1.438A12.172,12.172,0,0,0,54.231,39.511Z" transform="translate(49.291 10.333)"/><path class="a" d="M52,7.879h7.668l.719,4.074h.479A14.274,14.274,0,0,1,65.9,8.6a18,18,0,0,1,6.231-1.2,13.509,13.509,0,0,1,9.346,3.355c2.4,2.157,3.355,5.991,3.355,11.023v24.2H75.724V22.257c0-2.636-.479-4.313-1.677-5.512-.959-1.2-2.636-1.677-4.793-1.677a10.384,10.384,0,0,0-4.553.959A14.619,14.619,0,0,0,60.867,18.9V45.742H52Z" transform="translate(72.611 10.333)"/><path class="a" d="M97.454,7.6,87.15,37.794,77.085,7.6H67.5L81.4,45.7h2.636L78.284,61.039H87.15L106.561,7.6H97.454ZM84.993,59.841a3.406,3.406,0,0,1-1.438.479,2.026,2.026,0,0,1-1.438-.479c-.479-.24-.479-.719-.479-1.438a2.569,2.569,0,0,1,.479-1.438,3.406,3.406,0,0,1,1.438-.479,2.026,2.026,0,0,1,1.438.479c.479.24.479.719.479,1.438S85.473,59.6,84.993,59.841Z" transform="translate(94.254 10.612)"/></g><g transform="translate(185.174 54.397)"><path class="a" d="M87.015,37.557h8.627v2.4H83.9V22.7H95.4v2.4H86.776v4.553H94.2v2.4H86.776v5.512Z" transform="translate(-66.407 -22.7)"/><path class="a" d="M94.712,39.954V25.336H89.2V22.7h14.139v2.636H97.827V39.954Z" transform="translate(-59.006 -22.7)"/><g transform="translate(0 0)"><path class="a" d="M76.6,33.248V36.6h2.876V25.1Z" transform="translate(-76.6 -19.349)"/><path class="a" d="M86.048,35.4,79.1,24.617l-1.2,3.115,7.908,12.221h3.115V22.7H86.048Z" transform="translate(-74.785 -22.7)"/></g></g></g></svg>',
        socials: []
      }
    },
    created () {
      this.$http.get('/static/json/data.json').then(function ({data}) {
        this.socials = data.frontPage.social
        console.log(this.data)
      })
    }
  }
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .logo {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 15px;
  }

  .circle {
    background: #fff url(/static/img/me.acf533d.svg) no-repeat -40px 20px;
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .socialCircle {
    background: #fff;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header  header  header"
      "content content content"
      "footer footer footer";
    color: #444;
    align-items: stretch;
  }

  .box {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 150%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .header {
    grid-area: header;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .content {
    grid-area: content;
    height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    background: #333;
  }

  .footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    height: 100px;
    background: #222;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/0e54aq5n/ Please share your code and the errors you're getting

Comment: You used just jQuery and didn't use VueJS.

I try to implement this into VueJS.

Thanks!

Comment: The fiddle doesn't use jQuery anywhere and I did use VueJS (it's below the MoonMap code). I'm voting to close this question since you have not provided your code, errors, or sufficient context. Here's the help page on how to provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edit my post.

i see now the VueJS but you used a different implementation than I did.
I wanna implement it into a VueJS Template *.vue file.

Comment: Is there a way you can help me out @thanksd?
The steps that I did were to start a clean vue-cli project using WebStorm and then I created a folder ./src/scripts/moonmap/

Then I went to main.js and added the created as you did on jsfiffle and added import MoonMap from './scripts/moonmap/moonMap'

But I can figure out what am I doing wrong.

Thanks for your help!